# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2 on xCode while trying to append a char to a string in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to append a char to a string in C but it keeps throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 2 error at the the function I'm using

```
void append(char s[], char c)
{
    char str[strlen(s)+1];
    strcpy (str,s);
    char x[2];
    x[0]=c;x[1]='\0';
    strcat(s, x);
}
```

The caller function, as you can see it is used to create a postfix equation out of an infix equation

```
const char * postFix(char x[]){
    PtrToNode P = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    P->Next=NULL;
    char* m="";
    char open='(',close=')';
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(x);i++){
        if (x[i]!='+'&&x[i]!='-'&&x[i]!='*'&&x[i]!='/'&&x[i]!='%'&&x[i]!='('&&x[i]!=')'){
            if (x[i+1]!='+'&&x[i+1]!='-'&&x[i+1]!='*'&&x[i+1]!='/'&&x[i+1]!='%'&&x[i+1]!='('&&x[i+1]!=')'){
                append(m, open);
                append(m, x[i]);
                append(m, x[i+1]);
                append(m, close);
            }
            else
                append(m, x[i]);
        }
        else {
            if (x[i]=='(')
                Push(x[i], P);
            else if (x[i]==')'){
                PtrToNode PTN= P->Next;
                char ch=Pop(P);
                while (ch!='(') {
                    append(m,PTN->Element);
                    ch=Pop(P);
                }
            }
            else {
                char peak=Peak(P);
                if (peak=='+'||peak=='-'){
                    if (x[i]=='*'||x[i]=='/'||x[i]=='%'){
                        Push(x[i], P);
                    }
                    else {
                        char whatever = Pop(P);
                        Push(x[i], P);
                        append(m,whatever);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (peak=='*'||peak=='/'||peak=='%'){
                        char whatever = Pop(P);
                        append(m,whatever);
                        Push(x[i], P);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s",m);
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line is throwing the error? What is `s` and `c`?

Comment: Can you include the caller function ?

Comment: I point to this line in the assembly code as the line where it goes wrong .. 0x7fff8c7f89f6:  movb   %cl, (%r8,%rdx), the s is the string and the c is the letter I want to add to s

Answer (score 2):

Either:

A) what `s` refers to is not modifiable, or
B) `s` is not large enough to hold `strlen(s) + 2` characters

EDIT: You posted your code, and the answer is... both, but A is more pressing.

```
char* m=""; 
/* ... */
append(m, open);
```

`m` is a non-modifiable string.  Any attempt to modify a string literal allocated in such away results in undefined behavior.  Even if it were modifiable, it is not large enough to concatenate another character to without reallocation.

If you wish to alter what `m` refers to, then allocate it like so:

```
char m[size];
```

or

```
char *m = malloc(size);
```

Additionally, you will need to allocated enough room for the largest possible concatenated string up front or, alternatively, allocate more memory before calling `append`.

As an aside, `str` in `append` is unused and completely unnecessary.

Comment: How to know which is of these is the problem ?

Comment: Because I can reason about this stuff, and, by far, the most common cause for beginners is attempting to modify a string literal.  Experience and all.  I added an update after your recent addition.

Comment: I followed your advice and allocated memory in advance but now this happens, The string I send as a parameter to postFix is char x[] ="2+5*12"; and it outputs h25(12)(2)h25(12)(2), where did the h come from !!!!